# Silverlight 5 Unit testing in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2012

The 'Silverlight Unit Test Application' project type is missing from within Visual Studio 2012.
I can see it in VS 2010, but not in VS2012.
I have installed and re-installed the Silverlight 5 toolkit from codeplex.
Creating and running a silverlight unit test project in VS2010 works, but when running the tests through R# in VS2012, I get "Inconclusive: Test wasn't run"

Any help / suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is R#? Do you mean resharper?

Comment: Hi Eriawan, yes. Resharper Version 7.1

Comment: I found [workaround][1] for almost same question, may help .


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28167112/173073

Answer (score 4):

This link has the answer that worked for me:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5e991b0d-8061-4c4e-a17d-82b4abd58d6c/vs-2012-silverlight-unittest

> I recommend starting a new Silverlight project and installing the
>   SilverlightToolkit-Testing NuGet package. In your test files, put in
>   usings for Microsoft.Silverlight.Testing and
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting and use regular
>   [TestClass] and [TestMethod] attributes. To run them, you can use the
>   Toolkit test runner by putting `RootVisual =
>   UnitTestSystem.CreateTestPage();` in your App.Application_Startup(),
>   use Silverlight Unit Test Adapter (which currently is at v0.0.1 and
>   doesn't really work), or (the best approach by far) install ReSharper
>   and the AgUnit plugin.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to reference Silverlight libraries from ordinary .NET libraries. So, if you are going to unit test only your view models, you can move them to a separate project, create an ordinary (not Silverlight specific) unit testing project and add a reference to the project of view models.